# Truncated Options in Commons Cli are wrongly accepted

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

The code

```
private static void buildMyCliOptions() { 


             optionsMyAdd.addOption(Option.builder()
                         .longOpt("my-address")
                         .argName("property=value")
                         .hasArg()
                         .desc("Specify Address")
                         .required()
                         .build());


             optionsMyAdd.addOption(Option.builder()
                         .longOpt("My-port")
                         .argName("property=value") 
                         .hasArgs()
                         .valueSeparator()
                         .desc("Specify port")
                         .required()
                         .build());

         } 


tempOptions = ParseCommand.getOptionsMyAdd();
commandLine = cmdLineParser.parse(tempOptions, ParseCommand.args,true);
```

when I give a command like:

```
add --my-addr=example1  --my-port=example2
```

it is accepted even if my-address option is truncated.

How could avoid it is accepted and allow only the complete --my-address option?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Apache commons-cli that cannot be turned off as far as I see.

It is done at [org.apache.commons.cli.Options.java:287](https://github.com/apache/commons-cli/blob/18f8576896a0200097dff9f48ffe010e75a1a92d/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/cli/Options.java#L286) and I don't see a way to turn it off.

So your only "option" is probably a feature request for commons-cli at https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa